# mysql query displaying #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

i tried to search but not my kind problem i found in example...i have one query that i want to perform in mysql but it displays error #1064.here,my query

```
UPDATE address_tbl SET title='AARYA-VEER COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING AND TECHNOLOGY',add='Kuvadva-Sardhar Road, National Highway-8B',city='Rajkot jam',state='GUJARAT',country='INDIA',pin='360023',contact1='+91-7575808506',contact2='+91-7575808551/52',mail='info@aaryaveercampus.edu.in',web='www.aaryaveercampus.edu.in' WHERE id=1;
```

if i remove add='Kuvadva-Sardhar Road, National Highway-8B' field than it works fine but i want to change that also.and field name is add in table 100%.please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`add` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be escaped by backticks.

```
... `add` = 'K...
```